# Escaping ' from mySQL array

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, special-characters, longtext

There is some text stored in mysql table as long text. It contains ' characters.

Trying to escape these so I can fetch the results. Anything having ' gives error.

review_text with ' fails to bring back anything. The answer is supposed to be with mysql_real_escape_string but that's not working.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $review = array();
    $review["name"] = $row["reviewer_name"];
    $review["title"] = $row["review_title"];
    $review["content"] = $row["review_text"];
    $review["rating"] = $row["review_rating"];
    $review["time"] = $row["date_time"];
    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["reviews"], $review);
}
```

Comment: you don't need to escape it if it's for viewing. If there's no user input, then I don't see why you'd want to "escape" anything. If you really want to, then use `stripslashes` http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php even then, that may not be what you want. Like I said, there's no need to escape it if it's just for displaying purposes.

Comment: good point @Fred-ii-   I find it is easier to use prepared statements, no need to escape, `stripslashes` etc.  with all the added benefits

Comment: *"Anything having `'` gives error."* - Show us that error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm guessing that it ends or starts a string breaking anything after it. ;)

Comment: I can't think of an instance where a `'` being present in your provided code would cause an issue. Perhaps you went too minimal?

Comment: @nomistic hard to say till we know what the *real* purpose is.

Comment: @Fred -ii- In my database, there is a field called review_text.
So the ' is present in the review text part.The review_text field is of  Long Text type. I want to print that data using PHP, but its not printing anything.  Please let me know if there is a way to print the data with ' or %.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of handling this, however first of you need to stop using deprecated `mysql_` extensions.   "Deprecated" means that they are no longer included within php, and soon will stop working, as it states on the official php site here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

> **Warning**
>
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> ```
> mysqli_fetch_array()
> PDOStatement::fetch()
> ```

You can use mysqli_real_escape_string to "escape" your variables, however it's much better to use prepared statements.   Either `mysqli_` or `PDO` will work.

In this case where you are getting the variables using a select, you can do as follows (it's not clear where you are getting your variables but let's use this as an assumption), you would connect to your database like so:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if  ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbc->connect_error);

$stmt = $conn->prepare(select name, title, content, rating, time from tablename where variable = ?);
// this is assuming that this is a string, so "s" is used, otherwise use "i" for string
$stmt->bind_param("s",$variable);
$stmt->execute();
//then you can bind your results into tidy variables all of which have been "escaped"
$stmt->bind_result($name, $title, $content, $rating, $time);
$stmt->close();
```

To get your variables, insteady of using `mysql_fetch_array()` you just use `$stmt->fetch();`

or like this:

```
while (stmt->fetch()) {
    [stuff here]
}
```

voila, your variables are pretty clean.   **Note:** while these will handle quotations, apostrophes, etc, they will also be much more secure for protection against SQL injecction.  You can also use PDO.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :) To help future users it's good to check  the correct answer